# Using dynamic value when calling a Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Suppose i have a plugin for eg. zoom . I want to know if it is possible to use a dynamic value   in it when calling

eg

```
var times=$('.times').val();

$('img').zoom({
quality:10,
zoomtimes : times //can i use variable defined above here ?
})
```

HTML

```
 <input type="hidden" class="times" value="2">
```

Comment: I don't see why not - have you tried it?

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ Yes i have tries but it takes the default value defined by the plugin

Comment: what is the value stored in variable times, if your plugin is expecting a float or integer try using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` as needed

Comment: @Ravi Hamsa I have tried everything. It just doesnt take the value. My original question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535297/using-jquery-to-change-maxfile-in-weixiyen-file-drop-plugin